# Google Apps Free transfer domain hosting

Tags: google-workspace

I'm currently using Google Apps Free (50 users). And the domain were registered via Google Apps with US$10 yearly.

For some reason, I need to transfer this domain to my another hosting. Is that possible to transfer without affecting the Google Apps services?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. From: [Transfer your domain to another host - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/171715?hl=en)

> When you change your domain host there's no need to make any changes
>   to your Google Apps account - you simply need to update the CNAME and
>   MX records managed by the new domain host.